# How do I bundle a library within a Cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa

I have the library `libmysqlclient.16.dylib`, which I need to have on the computer where my application is running, or I will get the following error:

> Dyld Error Message:   Library not
>   loaded:
>   /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_r.16.dylib
>   Referenced from: /Users/alex/snow
>   server 3.app/Contents/MacOS/snow
>   server   Reason: image not found

This is very strange, because I linked the binary with this library.

If the same dylib exists on the target computer, but in a different version (for example, Snow Leopard Server), I get an error like the following:

> Dyld Error Message:   Library not
>   loaded:
>   /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_r.16.dylib
>   Referenced from: /Users/alex/snow
>   server 3.app/Contents/MacOS/snow
>   server   Reason: no suitable image
>   found.  Did find:
>     /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_r.16.dylib:
>   mach-o, but wrong architecture

I'd like to link against this library, but not have to use the local copy of it.  Is this possible?

UPDATE - when i try to using install_name_tool i don't have any changes:

> bash-3.2# otool -L
>   libmysqlclient.16.dylib 
>   libmysqlclient.16.dylib:
>     libmysqlclient.16.dylib
>   (compatibility version 16.0.0, current
>   version 16.0.0)
>     /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>   (compatibility version 1.0.0, current
>   version 123.0.0)
>     /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility
>   version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.3)
>     /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
>   (compatibility version 7.0.0, current
>   version 7.9.0) bash-3.2# 
>   install_name_tool -change
>   libmysqlclient.16.dylib
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/libmysqlclient.16.dylib
>   Usage: install_name_tool [-change old
>   new] ... [-rpath old new] ...
>   [-add_rpath new] ... [-delete_rpath
>   old] ... [-id name] input bash-3.2# 
>   install_name_tool -change
>   libmysqlclient.16.dylib
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/libmysqlclient.16.dylib
>   libmysqlclient.16.dylib bash-3.2#
>   otool -L libmysqlclient.16.dylib 
>   libmysqlclient.16.dylib:
>     libmysqlclient.16.dylib
>   (compatibility version 16.0.0, current
>   version 16.0.0)
>     /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>   (compatibility version 1.0.0, current
>   version 123.0.0)
>     /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility
>   version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.3)
>     /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
>   (compatibility version 7.0.0, current
>   version 7.9.0)

**SOLUTION**
i was add a script into build phase:
install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.16.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libmysqlclient.16.dylib $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/Contents/MacOS/$PRODUCT_NAME
this was fixed a libpath for executive product and working fine with lib in bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll want to make sure that you're copying this library into your application bundle so that it will be available on the user's machine.  To do this, add a new Copy Files build phase for your application to copy bundled frameworks.  Within the properties of that build phase, make sure that the destination is Frameworks.  Drag your library from your project into that build phase to make sure that it is packaged with your application.

You may also need to modify the library itself so that it points to the correct location within the application bundle.  In the past, I've done this by making a copy of the library within my project's directory, then using the following command to modify where the library expects to find itself:

```
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/libftd2xx.0.1.0.dylib libftd2xx.0.1.0.dylib
```

In this case, the library being modified was called `libftd2xx.0.1.0.dylib`.

You can use the command

```
otool -L [library filename]
```

to see the path where the library expects itself to be found and determine if this change needs to be made.

Make sure that you change the path on the library within your Xcode project so that you will be linking against this new, modified version of the library residing within your project directory.

Comment: if i will using libmysql.a - it's mean that library will be in code without dynamic loading and i don't need to make any copy?

Comment: @Alex - Yes, if you use a static library it will be linked into your binary.  However, be very careful with the licensing of your library to make sure that you aren't contaminating your application by doing so.  First, you'll need to use one of the LGPL versions of MySQL, because the base version is GPL: http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/index.html .  If you link in an LGPL static library, you may need to release the object files for your application to comply with the LGPL license.  Odds are, you're using the GPL version of MySQL here, so you'll need to pay for a commercial license.

Comment: tnx, but i was do a same as u tell and have error: dyld: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/snow-dnqbsbmaqlhtddanrxjajfdqlqtf/Build/Products/Debug/snow server.app/Contents/MacOS/snow server
  Reason: image not found
i was add copy files phase and add my libmysqlclient.16.dylib (destination - frameworks)

Comment: install_name_tool - where is have to be start this command? i already have my lib in bundle, but application is still don't load it